# Make a registry change based on OS version

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a reg key change based on the OS version.
The Key change pat works fine however the if function to work out if the device needs it or not I can not get to work. Any advice would be helpful. The powershell is below.

```
$verCheckOS = (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).version
    
if ($verCheckOS -lt 10.0.19043 -and $verCheckOS -gt 10.0.17134)
{
    if (Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\AzureADAccount)
    {
        CD HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft
        New-Item -Name AzureADAccount
        New-ItemProperty -Path "AzureADAccount" -Name "AllowPasswordReset" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWord
    }
}
Else
{
}
```

Comment: Please provide some of the issues, errors you are getting with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make PowerShell compare version numbers properly you need to cast them to the proper type.

```
$verCheckOS = [version](Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version 
if ($verCheckOS -lt [version]'10.0.19043' -and $verCheckOS -gt [version]'10.0.17134') {
    if (-not (Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\AzureADAccount)) {
        Push-Location 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft'
        New-Item -Name 'AzureADAccount' 
        New-ItemProperty -Path 'AzureADAccount' -Name 'AllowPasswordReset' -Value 1 -PropertyType DWord
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$verCheckOS = (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).version        
if ($verCheckOS -lt "10.0.19043" -and $verCheckOS -gt "10.0.17134")
{
    if (!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\AzureADAccount"))
    {
        $null = New-Item -Name "AzureADAccount" -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\"
        $null = New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\AzureADAccount" -Name "AllowPasswordReset" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWord
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused by your code.  You check if the full path to the AzureADAccount key exists and then if it does you proceed to try and create it?  I think you meant if it does NOT exist then create it?  I mean your code won't execute if it isn't there so the line to create it is just going to error out.  So I changed it to run the block only if the path doesn't exist.  If that's wrong then put the Test-Path line back the way you had it and remove the 'New-Item -Name "AzureADAccount"' line as its meaningless and keep the New-ItemProperty line.

Also just adding quotes around the numbers made the version check if statement work fine for me in my testing.

Comment: I would caution against simply quoting numbers to use with `-lt`,`-gt` comparisons. String comparisons use alphabetic order rather than numeric order. Example: `"15" -lt "1440"` evaluates to False because 15 is not less than 14.